# Snake Game - Can't get snake body to follow snake head

Tags: c++, sfml

I have been working on a snake game using sfml and c++ but I am having trouble getting the tail of my snake to follow the snake head which is defined as Snake[0] in my code below. I have implemented code that I think should work but doesn't which is the following

```
    for (int i = 1; i < snakeSize; i++)
    {
        snakePartX[i] = snakePartX[i-1];
        snakePartY[i] = snakePartY[i-1];
    }
```

The way I understand it (and I am probably incredibly wrong and would appreciate if anyone could point out what is actually happening here) is that, that piece of code should set the value of a snake body part to the position of where the previous body part WAS located so that when the program loops they are set to follow the snake as it travels.

What actually does happen though is that when the snake eats an apple the snake will gain 1 block to its tail, but will not grow any farther.

Comment: Side note :  you should use a list instead of a vector. Then you don't have to copy all the positions at each move.

Comment: @Caduchon: try timing that (if it matters for a snake game). list can give cache misses, vectors are contiguous.

Comment: @Caduchon: A dequeue would be a better structure for it allows for insertions at one end (the head) and removals at the other (the tail).

Comment: Tell me when I'm wrong, but in your for-loop you are setting all SnakePartX/Y to SnakePartX/Y [0]. You would have to iterate from the end to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

In the classic snake game, the snake is made up of segments.  Each segment contains the coordinate of the segment (among other attributes).

Specifically, the snake is a *container* of segments.  The container is your choice, but I recommend a queue.

With the queue, a new head segment is added into the queue and a tail segment removed.

Here's a code fragment to help:

```
class Snake_Segment
{
  public:
    int column;
    int row;
};

typedef std::deque<Snake_Segment> Segment_Container;

int main(void)
{
  Segment_Container snake_body;
  Snake_Segment head;
  head.row(25);
  head.column(30);
  snake_body.push_back(head);
  Snake_Segment tail = head;
  ++tail.column;
  snake_body.push_back(tail);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do index zero here?   Doesn't it get done as part of the for loop too?

```
        Snake[0].setPosition(snakePartX[0], snakePartY[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < snakeSize; i++)
        {
            Snake[i].setPosition(snakePartX[i], snakePartY[i]);
        }
```

I'm concerned about this section :

```
        snakeSize += 1;
    }

    Apple.setPosition(applePos.x, applePos.y);
    window.draw(Apple);

    for(int i = 0; i < snakeSize; i++)
    {
        window.draw(Snake[i]);
    }
```

Make sure you don't exceed 20 as your parts are a simple array and you will run into problems once you get 20 parts.   More importantly, you never set the value for Snake[i] for the new snakeSize.   So when you get an apple, you'll use uninitialized memory to draw one snake part.

Another potential problem  :

```
    //Clock to set snake speed
    ElapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
    if(ElapsedTime.asSeconds() >= snakeSpeed)
    {

        for(int i = 1; i < snakeSize; i++)
        {
            snakePartX[i] = snakePartX[i - 1];
            snakePartY[i] = snakePartY[i - 1];
        }
```

You allow keyboard input to move the snake head along, but you only move the body when the timer expires.   So you head can slide way away from the body and the body doesn't move unless the timer goes off.

Answer (score 0):

I printed the field of snake game as a `Field[x][y]`. So by below code the body of snake following the head. Also, `optionMoveNumber==0` in other function checked if `Field[x][y]==food` or not which means did the snake eat the food of not.

```
int m=1;
void Snake::Movement(int x, int y){
        movey[0]=firstTaily; //first place
        movex[0]=firstTailx; //first place
        movex[m]=x;
        movey[m]=y; 
        for(int n=m; n>=m-ntail; n--){
        Field[movey[n]][movex[n]]=Field[movey[n-1]][movex[n-1]];
    }
    if(optionMoveNumber==0){
        Field[movey[m-1]][movex[m-1]]=tail;
    }
    else{
        Field[movey[m-ntail-1]][movex[m-ntail-1]]=space;
    }
    m++;

}
```